# What happens to the back stack when re-opening an activity when launchMode="singleTask"?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Imagine an app where *Activity A* is the default Activity and has launchMode="singleTask". The app opens to Activity A. The user navigates through the app and at some point navigates to Activity A again (by moving forward, not pressing back). According to the Android docs, because launchMode="singleTask", this will happen:

> The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes
>   the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already
>   exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a
>   call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.

Activity A exists on the back stack, so it will receive a call to onNewIntent(). What I want to know is, **what happens to the other Activities when Activity A is brought from the bottom of the back stack to the top?**

Are they popped and destroyed or does something else happen? Are they even in the same stack?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: hi have you seen the answer, if yes and feasible to you than issue will be closed and we will move to next question after solving. :)

Answer (score 0):

From the Android docs:
  http://developer.android.com/images/fundamentals/diagram_backstack_singletask_multiactivity.png

`A representation of how an activity with launch mode "singleTask" is added to the back stack. If the activity is already a part of a background task with its own back stack, then the entire back stack also comes forward, on top of the current task.`